# Implementing a main menu in my Java game is generating an error with the createBufferStrategy(int)

Tags: java, game-development, java-2d

I'm working on a version of pacman using Java using Java 2D API and I tried to include a main menu to the game following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZWX5WoGW00&t=132s. When I try to get a black screen like he did in the video I get the error:

`Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer`

I tried changing the number of the buffers using `createBufferStrategy(int)` with 1 instead of 3, which was the default through the whole project and the error message changed to:

`Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException`

But this made the ghosts in the game start flickering

The code of the render function in the `Game` class, which I think is generating the problem, is this :

```
private void render() { 
        //Use with BufferedImage
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bufferStrategy == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(1);
            return;
        }
        Graphics graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        if(screen == ScreenID.GAME) {
            //First iteration: render whole map
            if (firstRender) {
                mapHandler.renderMap(graphics);
                firstRender = false;
            }      
            mapHandler.renderMap(graphics);
            entityHandler.render(graphics);
            graphics.dispose();
            bufferStrategy.show();
        } else if(screen == ScreenID.MENU) {
            menu.render(graphics);
            graphics.dispose();
            bufferStrategy.show();
        }
    }
```

And here is the `Window` class that is used to control the frames:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends Canvas {
    
    private JFrame frame;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height)); 
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        UserInput controls = new UserInput(game.player,game.screen); //Define os controles do jogo
        frame.add(controls);
        setFocusable(false);
        if(game.screen == ScreenID.GAME) {
            frame.add(game);
        }else if(game.screen == ScreenID.MENU) {
            JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
            JButton buttonGame = new JButton("Jogo");
            myPanel.add(buttonGame);
            JButton buttonCredits = new JButton("Créditos");
            myPanel.add(buttonCredits);
            myPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            frame.add(myPanel);
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I will try to help you. Actually I also use that tutorial to make menu and I had everything worked.

1. Why does `Window` extends `Canvas` if you even don't put it in `Jframe`. It is useless;
2. If you use `game.start()` and then `Game.render()` it will be drawing on game that extends Canvas. But if `game.screen == ScreenID.MENU` returns true then you will have only `myPanel` on the `JFrame` and `Game.render()` will not draw.

Can you give me your code I will try to make something unless you have already done with it.